# Can you run cypress specs all as one test run so that the test records to testrail as one test run instead of a test run for each spec file?

Tags: cypress, testrail

I have been using this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-testrail-reporter
and it does not seem to have a reporter option to allow me to do this. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Sorry for the bit off topic, but you can have a look at another tool for exporting cypress results into TestRail - Railflow. It has its own cypress reporter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/railflow-cypress-junit-reporter.  
Disclaimer: Please note that this is a commercial product and I'm a developer of it

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.2.2 that is not possible. Nonetheless, you can still upgrade the package if deasync works well in your environment. Else, another option is to install other cypress-testrail-reporters removing the dependency on deasync.
[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mkonate/cypress-testrail-reporter) is the one I have been working on for instance

Comment: Thank you @Mohamed. By downgrading the version of cypress-testrail-reporters to 1.2.2, the problem is resolved.